# show keysize and keyalg of keystore entry

Tags: java, keystore, secret-key

I have a java keystore file that contains a secret key. It was created like this:

```
keytool -genseckey -alias mykey -keyalg AES -keysize 128 -storetype jceks -keystore keystore.jks
```

How can I retrieve the properties of the stored secret key? I need to show the "keyalg" and the "keysize".

I've looked at the `list` command, but it only gives me the date of creation, the alias and the type (i.e. secret key).

Comment: list already shows the algo used. As for size, that I don't know.

Comment: i dont even see the algo with `list`. can you show me the full command I should be using?